# Enemy not staying at original spot

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, pygame-surface

So I been trying make my enemy move at the same spot while my player moves the camera but it's not working, when the screen moves my enemy will slowly move from its original spot but once its out of its original spot it will start glitching. Also when my player collides with a side of a platform my enemy will move the same way as my player but faster e.g.: https://gyazo.com/926207e82cd9849266decd68c08ea84d

A part of my camera movement(Not working)

```
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(-playerman.speed,0)
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "right"
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")


move = pygame.image.load("WASD.png")


# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.idle =[pygame.image.load("player_idel_1.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_2.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_3.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_4.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_5.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_6.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_7.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_8.png")
                            ]

        self.idlel = [pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left1.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left2.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left3.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left4.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left5.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left6.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left7.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left8.png")
                         ]
        self.right = [pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right3.png")]
        
        self.left = [pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left3.png")]

        self.jump1 = [pygame.image.load("Player_jump5.png")]

        
        self.jump2 = [
                     pygame.image.load("Player_rjump1.png")]
        

        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.idle = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.idle]
        self.idlel = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.idlel]
        self.right = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.right]
        self.left = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2, image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.left]
        self.jump1 = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.jump1]
        self.jump2 = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.jump2]
        self.fps = 10
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.direction = "idle"
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.dierection = "idleleft"
        self.dierection = "jump1"
        self.dierection = "jump2"
        self.next_frame_time = 0
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
        pygame.draw.rect(self.color,self.rect)
    
    def draw(self):
        if self.direction == "idle":
            image_list = self.idle
        if self.direction == "right":
            image_list = self.right
        if self.direction == "left":
            image_list = self.left
        if self.direction == "idlel":
            image_list = self.idlel
        if self.direction == "jump1":
            image_list = self.jump1
        if self.direction == "jump2":
            image_list = self.jump2
    

         

        # Is it time to show the next animation frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_frame_time ):
            # set the time for the next animation-frame
            inter_frame_delay = 1000 // self.fps   
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_frame_delay  # in the future
            # move the current image to the next (with wrap-around)
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len( image_list ):
                self.anim_index = 0
                    
        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        pygame.draw.rect( window, self.color, self.get_rect(), 2 )
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 3
        player_rect.centery -= 13
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)

class Snake:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.path = [x, end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.visible = True
        self.no = pygame.image.load("Player_jump5.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.move()
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.no,self.rect)

    def move(self):
        if self.visible:
            # turn around if the move would go out-of-bounds
            proposed_move = self.x + self.vel
            if ( proposed_move < self.path[0] or proposed_move > self.path[1] ):
                # Move hits a boundary, so we need to turn around
                self.vel = -self.vel
                self.Walking_index = 0
            # now make the correct move
            self.x += self.vel   # add +/- velocity
    def scroll(self,sx,sy):
        self.x += sx
        self.y += sy
        self.path[0] += sx
        self.path[1] += sx


class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())


class Rule:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)


# Colors for hitbox
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(350,445,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(300,-9.1,40,500,green)
platform2 = Platform(330,451,2000,40,green)
platform3 = Platform(2300,-9.1,40,500,green)

# Drawing Rule
rule1 = Rule(340,-9.1,220,500,green)
rule2 = Rule(20000,-9,1,5,green)

snake1 = Snake(100, 110, 64, 64, 300)

# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2,platform3]

rules = [rule1,rule2]

snakes = [snake1]


# draws map
platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
Level = [
"                                         1   1",
"                                         1    ",
"                         1  1        111 1    ",
"                         1  1         1  1    ",
"                         11 1      1  1 11    ",
"                         1  1         1  1    ",
"                         1  1    1    11 1    ",
"           1   1   111   1 11         1  1    ",
"           1   1  11111        1      1          ",]

for iy,row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_platforms = Platform(ix*50,iy*50.2,50,50,(255,255,255))
            platforms.append(new_platforms)
    
            

# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    # Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()
    for Rule in rules:
        Rule.draw()
    for Snake in snakes:
        Snake.draw()

x = 10
y = 10
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    
            

        


 # part of player screen movment
    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += playerman.speed

        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(0, +playerman.speed)

    if playerman.y > 410:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y -= playerman.fall
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(0, -playerman.fall)

    # part of side colliding    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            x_change = -7
            for Snake in snakes:
                Snake.scroll(playerman.speed,0)
            
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 7
            for Snake in snakes:
                Snake.scroll(-playerman.speed,0)

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x
           
        # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y

    for Platform in platforms:    
        if playerman.fall > 0 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                playerman.direction = "jump1"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "left":
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    playerman.direction = "jump2"

               

 # direction for player animation and screen movment
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(-playerman.speed,0)
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "right"

        
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "left"
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(playerman.speed,0)






            
    else:
        if playerman.direction == "left" and playerman.direction == "idlel":
         
            playerman.direction = "idlel"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "right" and playerman.direction == "idle":
                
                playerman.direction = "idle"


    if playerman.direction == "right" and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        playerman.direction = "jump1"
            
    if playerman.direction == "left":
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            playerman.direction = "jump2"

    
    # sides for player and player screen movment
    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px

    move_right = keys[pygame.K_d]
    move_left = keys[pygame.K_a]
    if move_right: 
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed     # <---
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(-playerman.speed,0)

    if move_left:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed     # <---
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(playerman.speed,0)

    platform_rect_list = [p.get_rect() for p in platforms] # get_rect()
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    cI = player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list)
    if cI >= 0:
        # undo movement of platforms dependent on the direction and intersection distance
        dx = 0
        if move_right: 
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].left - player_rect.right
        if move_left:
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].right - player_rect.left
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= dx
            Platform.get_rect() # update rectangle
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= dx             # <---
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.x -= dx


##############                
  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
                       
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                py -= playerman.speed
            playerman.fall = 0
            

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    redrawwindow()
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(rule1.rect):
        window.blit(move,(-40,-100))
    
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improve the robustness of your code. Make sure that the movement of a `Snake` works even if the position of the snake is far out of the `path`. If `proposed_move` is less than `self.path[0]-self.vel` or `self.path[1]+self.vel`, then the `Snake` will never return to the path, because `self.vel` will be inverted continuously. Make sure that the direction of movement is always set to the right if `proposed_move < self.path[0]` and make sure that the direction of movement is always set to the left if `proposed_move > self.path[1]`:

```py
class Snake:
    # [...]

    def move(self):
        if self.visible:
            # turn around if the move would go out-of-bounds
            proposed_move = self.x + self.vel

            # Move hits a boundary, so we need to turn around
            if proposed_move < self.path[0]:
                self.vel = abs(self.vel)
                self.Walking_index = 0
            if proposed_move > self.path[1]:
                self.vel = -abs(self.vel)
                self.Walking_index = 0

            # now make the correct move
            self.x += self.vel   # add +/- velocity
```

Do the same for `Bat`:

```py
class Bat:
    # [...]

    def move(self):
        if self.visible:
            # relizes when it hits bounds
            proposed_move = self.x + self.vel
            if proposed_move < self.path[0]:
                self.vel = abs(self.vel)
                self.Walking_index = 0
            if proposed_move > self.path[1]:
                self.vel = -abs(self.vel)
                self.Walking_index = 0
                # starting movment
            self.x += self.vel
```

---

You have to simplify your code.

Store the initial position of the player (`start_x`, `start_y`) and a to methods to the class player that return the current position of the player in relation to the start position (`get_x`, `get_y`):

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.start_x = x
        self.start_y = y
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        #[...]

    def get_x(self):
        return self.x - self.start_x
    def get_y(self):
        return self.y - self.start_y
```

Compute the positions of `Snake`,  `Bat`, `Platform` and `Rule` in relation to the player:

```py
class Snake:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        self.move()
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x-playerman.get_x(), self.y-playerman.get_y())
        window.blit(self.no,self.rect)
```

```py
class Bat:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        self.move()
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x-playerman.get_x(), self.y-playerman.get_y())
        window.blit(self.no, self.rect)
```

```py
class Platform:
    # [...]

    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x-playerman.get_x(), self.y-playerman.get_y())
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())
```

```py
class Rule:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x-playerman.get_x(), self.y-playerman.get_y())
```

Get rid of player movement compensation (`scroll` etc.). This is no longer necessary as the objects are drawn in relation to the player. Complete main loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
 
    # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if playerman.fall > 0 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            playerman.direction = "jump1"
    else:
        if playerman.direction == "left":
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.direction = "jump2"
 
    # direction for player animation and screen movment x
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "right"
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "left"
    
    if playerman.direction == "right" and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        playerman.direction = "jump1"
    if playerman.direction == "left" and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        playerman.direction = "jump2"
 
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y

    # sides for player and player screen movment
    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)
 
    playerman.y = py
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) > 0:
        playerman.x = px      
 
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False
 
        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
            player_rect.topleft = (playerman.x, playerman.y)   
            platform_rect = Platform.get_rect()
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(platform_rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                if platform_rect.top > playerman.x:
                    playerman.y = platform_rect.top - playerman.height
                if player_rect.right > platform_rect.left and player_rect.left < platform_rect.left:
                    playerman.x = platform_rect.left - playerman.width
                if player_rect.left < platform_rect.right and player_rect.right > platform_rect.right:
                    playerman.x = platform_rect.right
 
            # colliding with floor      
            if player_rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height
 
        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                playerman.y -= playerman.speed
            playerman.fall = 0
 
 
    # Jump Count
 
    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
 
    redrawwindow()
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(rule1.rect):
        window.blit(move,(-40,-100))
 
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: So, every time I touch the sides of my platform is messes up the movement https://gyazo.com/0c25eef02a971d7b69b65eff40f330f2

Comment: I just deleted the bats, and I'm still getting the problem I don't know why.

Comment: Its that every single time I touch the sides of my platform, my enemy stop moving left and right and will move the say the player is. Like if I press d while colliding with the side of my platform, my enemy will move right