# Sprite image rectangle moving too fast

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying make it so my water rise like lava at the speed of 1 but every time my screen goes up:

```
    # Mkaing screen go up
    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 9
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += 9
        for Platform2 in Platforms:
            Platform2.y += 9
        for Dirt in dirts:
            Dirt.y += 9
```

The water sprite will get faster. https://gyazo.com/1bdd7b513a06f6a80832e565255e9fb0  How do I make it so the water sprite will keep on moving the same speed even if the screen moves. No matter how fast I keep moving up the water will just stay in the same spot and keep rising

My full code

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption(("Noobs First Game"))

# Player class
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 6
        self.fall = 0
        self.idle = [pygame.image.load("Player_idle1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle3.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle4.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle5.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle6.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle7.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle8.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle9.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle10.png")]
        
        self.idlel = [pygame.image.load("Player_lidle1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle3.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle4.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle5.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle6.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle7.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle8.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle9.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_lidle10.png")]

        self.run = [pygame.image.load("Player_run1.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_run2.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_run3.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_run4.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_run5.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_run6.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_run7.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_run8.png")]
        
        self.jump = [pygame.image.load("Player_Jump.png")]

        self.lrun = [pygame.image.load("Player_lrun1.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_lrun2.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_lrun3.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_lrun4.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_lrun5.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_lrun6.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_lrun7.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("Player_lrun8.png")]

        self.ljump = [pygame.image.load("Player_lJump.png")]

        self.direction = "run"
        self.direction = "jump"
        self.direction = "lrun"
        self.direction = "ljump"
        self.direction = "idle"
        self.direction = "idlel"
        self.run = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.run]
        self.jump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.jump]
        self.lrun = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.lrun]
        self.ljump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.ljump]
        self.idle = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.idle]
        self.idlel = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//6,image.get_height()//6))for image in self.idlel]

        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.next_frame_time = 0
        self.fps = 10
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.jump_height = 2
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        if self.direction == "run":
            image_list = self.run
        if self.direction == "jump":
            image_list = self.jump
        if self.direction == "lrun":
            image_list = self.lrun
        if self.direction == "ljump":
            image_list = self.ljump
        if self.direction == "idle":
            image_list = self.idle
        if self.direction == "idlel":
            image_list = self.idlel
            

        # Is it time to show next frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if (time_now > self.next_frame_time):
            # seconds till next frame
            inter_time_delay = 1000 // self.fps
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_time_delay
            # switch to next frame
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                self.anim_index = 0

        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        pygame.draw.rect( window, self.color, self.get_rect(), 2 )
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 3
        player_rect.centery -= 17
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)

# Platform class
class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.log = pygame.image.load("log.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.log = pygame.transform.scale(self.log,(self.log.get_width()//4,self.log.get_height()//6))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        platform_rect = self.log.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        platform_rect.centerx += 60
        platform_rect.centery -= 2
        window.blit(self.log,platform_rect)


# Platform2 class
class Platform2:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.log = pygame.image.load("Grass_1.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.log = pygame.transform.scale(self.log,(self.log.get_width()-90,self.log.get_height()-91))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        platform_rect = self.log.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        platform_rect.centerx += 2
        platform_rect.centery += 0.2
        window.blit(self.log,platform_rect)

class Dirt:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.dirt = pygame.image.load("Dirt_1.png")
        self.dirt = pygame.transform.scale(self.dirt,(self.dirt.get_width()-90,self.dirt.get_height()-91))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        dirt_rect = self.dirt.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        dirt_rect.centerx += 2
        dirt_rect.centery += 0.2
        window.blit(self.dirt,dirt_rect)

class Water:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 1
        self.water = pygame.image.load("water_1.png")
        self.water = pygame.transform.scale(self.water,(self.water.get_width()*8,self.water.get_height()*6))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

        water_rect = self.water.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        water_rect.centerx += 25
        water_rect.centery += 80
        window.blit(self.water,water_rect)

# displaying Color
white = (255,255,255)

# Drawing stuff

# Drawing player
playerman = Player(255,440,40,40,white)
# Drawing Platform
platform1 = Platform(0,388,130,30,white)
# Drawing Platform2
Platform1 = Platform2(7000,470,1,1,white)
# Drawing Dirt
dirt1 = Dirt(7000,255,35,35.1,white)
# Water
water1 = Water(0,800,500,300,white)
# List

# Putting Platform in a list
platforms = [platform1]
# Putting Platform2 in a list
Platforms = [Platform1]
# Putting Dirt in a list
dirts = [dirt1]

platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
Level = [
"  l",
"l",
"",
"  l",
"  ",
"l",
"   ",
"  l",
"   ",
"",
"",
"",
"11111111111111111111",
"22222222222222222222",]
for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_platform = Platform2(ix*35, iy*36.4, 35,35.1,(255, 255, 255))
            Platforms.append(new_platform)
for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "2":
            new_dirt = Dirt(ix*35, iy*36.4, 35,35.1,(255, 255, 255))
            dirts.append(new_dirt)
for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "l":
            new_platform = Platform(ix*110, iy*60, 130,30,(255, 255, 255))
            platforms.append(new_platform)
    


# redrawing window
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    
    # bliting a counter the game
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    # showing player on the screen
    playerman.draw()

    # Drawing Platform
    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()
    # Drawing Platform2
    for Platform2 in Platforms:
        Platform2.draw()
    # Drawing Dirt
    for Dirt in dirts:
        Dirt.draw()
        # Drawing Water
        water1.draw()
        

# The conter and how its going look like
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
score = 0
text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = ((150,40))


fps = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 10
y = 10

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

old_x = x
old_y = y

timer = 0
Stimer =  0
# Space down = False
spcdown = False
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    water1.y -= 1

    for Platform in platforms:
        if Platform.y > 510:
            Platform.x = random.randint(0, 500)
            Platform.y = random.randint(-150, -100)
            
    # Mkaing screen go up
    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 9
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += 9
        for Platform2 in Platforms:
            Platform2.y += 9
        for Dirt in dirts:
            Dirt.y += 9
        water1.y += 1

            
    # Marking screen go down
    if playerman.y > 410:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform2 in Platforms:
            Platform2.y -= playerman.fall
        for Dirt in dirts:
            Dirt.y -= playerman.fall
            



        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = -7
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 7

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 0

            x += x_change
            if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
                x = old_x


  

            
        

    # If keys get pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px,py = playerman.x,playerman.y




    # Adding one to score every time player jumps
    if not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        spcdown = False  # space released
    
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if not spcdown:
            score += 1  # if space pressed first time
        spcdown = True  # space key is pressed
        text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
        textRect.center = ((150,40))
        


    # Player movment
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
        px -= playerman.speed
        playerman.direction = "lrun"
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and px < 500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        px += playerman.speed
        playerman.direction = "run"
    else:
        if playerman.direction == "run":
            playerman.direction = "idle"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "lrun":
                playerman.direction = "idlel"
    

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and py > playerman.speed:
        py -= playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and py < 500 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        py += playerman.speed

    # animation for player jump
    if playerman.direction == "run":
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]: 
            playerman.direction = "jump"
    else:
        if playerman.direction == "lrun":
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.direction = "ljump"


    platform_rect_list =[p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    playerman.rect.topleft = (px,py)


    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px


    

        
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

                    

            # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right

        
                # Lets Player jump on top of second Platform
        for Platform2 in Platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform2.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform2.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform2.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform2.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform2.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform2.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform2.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform2.rect.right

                           
                # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

            # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.5
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

        
            
    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
quit_game
```

Comment: You have to move the water just like the platforms and any other object. You would not have these troubles if you had followed my suggestions: [Enemy not staying at original spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540452/enemy-not-staying-at-original-spot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the water just like the platforms and any other object. You would not have these troubles if you had followed my suggestions: [Enemy not staying at original spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540452/enemy-not-staying-at-original-spot).

Now you have to do it the "hard" way. The speed of the rising water level is controlled by:

> ```py
> while run:
>    # [...]
>
>    water1.y -= 1  # <--- Controls the rising water
> ```

If you want to increase the speed, you need to change the degree of decrement.

However, every time the player moves vertically, all objects in the scene must be shifted. Every time the platforms are shifted vertically due to the movement of the player, the water must also be shifted.

```py
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    water1.y -= 1                             # <--- Controls the rising water

    for Platform in platforms:
        if Platform.y > 510:
            Platform.x = random.randint(0, 500)
            Platform.y = random.randint(-150, -100)

    # Mkaing screen go up
    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 9
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += 9
        for Platform2 in Platforms:
            Platform2.y += 9
        for Dirt in dirts:
            Dirt.y += 9
        water1.y += 9                         # <--- shift vertically

    # Marking screen go down
    if playerman.y > 410:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform2 in Platforms:
            Platform2.y -= playerman.fall
        for Dirt in dirts:
            Dirt.y -= playerman.fall
        water1.y -= playerman.fall            # <--- shift vertically
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply change the value that you're adding to the coordinate to something lower to change the speed. I'd also recommend storing the value in a variable and using that variable in the add statement, that way, you only have to edit it at one place, check the code here:

```
if playerman.y < 250:
        delta = 6
        playerman.y += delta
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += delta
        for Platform2 in Platforms:
            Platform2.y += delta
        for Dirt in dirts:
            Dirt.y += delta
```

Comment: I did this but every time my water is in my screen, no mater how fast I move, I will catch up to me even thought I'm moving faster then it and its only moving at a speed of 1.

Comment: I think that's more of a problem logic problem than one with the values...

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the amount the water moves down when the player jumps up